# Backup MySQL Database without mysqldumb or mysql installed

Tags: server, ssh, backup, mysql

After Updating My Linux OS , The OS was not booting up i was havint /bin/init missing error or something. i managed to load install-amd4-minimal. I have made backup of files but i am not sure how to make a backup of backup of mysql databases.I have ftp/ssh access but i am not able to install mysql or anything. i just have access to files of the server. Please guide me to make a backup of the databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If MySQL is not currently running (in this case, it's not installed) you could grab the contents of `/var/lib/mysql/*`, and transfer them to a MySQL installation on another server.  You may need to ensure some aspects of the MySQL configuration is the same on both servers, and it is the same MySQL version.

This is not the normal recommended way to back up MySQL, but since MySQL is not running and you can't load it, this is worth trying - should work.